# Running Julia scripts from the terminal in a virtual environment

Tags: julia

I'm curious whether Julia supports the same workflow as Python + virtual environments.

In Python I can do the following from the terminal:

```sh
$ python -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install myFavPackage
(venv) $ python src/myFavScript.py
```

Julia can use virtual environments through its REPL like so:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> activate .
(myFavProject) pkg> add myFavPackage
julia> include("src/myFavScript.jl")
```

But if I run the first two lines (which adds all dependencies to the `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` files) and then jump out to the terminal and run

```sh
$ julia src/myFavScript.jl
```

Then it doesn't recognise the package I installed:

```sh
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package myFavPackage not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("myFavPackage")` to install the myFavPackage package.
```

Does this mean that I have to install my packages globally to run Julia scripts from the terminal? And if not, how can I force the terminal to use the local dependencies?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `--project` flag, i.e.

```
$ julia --project=path/to/project src/myFavScript.jl
```

If you are in the correct folder you can just omit the path, i.e.

```
$ julia --project src/myFavScript.jl
```

Finally, if you want this behavor by default, you can set the the `JULIA_PROJECT` environment variable to `@.`, which is equivalent to always starting Julia with `--project`.